# jquery closing overlay on both outer AND inner clicks?

Tags: jquery, click, overlay

I'm puzzled by something, thought someone here might have insight.

I've built a simple overlay, but it's not working as expected.
Here's the css:

```
    #overlayOuter {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #000;
        z-index: 100;
        }
    #overlayInner {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 200px;
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        z-index: 101;
        }
```

The html is simple:

```
    Blahblahblah!
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#overlayOuter').show();return false;">show overlay</a>
    <div id="overlayOuter">
        <div id="overlayInner">
            Oyeah? Blahblah!
        </div>
    </div>
```

I then wanted jquery to close the overlay when someone clicked on overlayOuter **but not** the overlayInner box (so I could include forms and such).

The first jquery I was expecting to work was ...

```
    $('#overlayOuter').click(function() {
        $('#overlayOuter').fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

... which works but strangely **also closes when clicking overlayInner**! Any forms, etc. are now useless!

The following ***does*** work as desired ...

```
    $('#overlayOuter').click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).parents('#overlayInner').length==0) {
            $('#overlayOuter').fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });
```

... but WTF!! Shouldn't the first one work? Isn't the z-index enough to mask overlayInner separate from overlayOuter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nesting the elements, so when you click the inner div, you're still clicking the outer.

you need to separate them like this:

```
<div id="overlayOuter">
</div>
<div id="overlayInner">
</div>
```

Not a problem with layout here that way, since you did set the position to absolute anyway

Here's the updated jfiddle from Stack 101s initially built one
http://jsfiddle.net/Dapuc/3/

Comment: thank you for this! embarrassed it didn't occur to me to try that :P

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Javascript event propagation/bubbling. Events that take place on an element will also take place on the elements containers. To avoid this, check that `event.target` is the element you want, like in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WQS3V/

Answer (score 0):

The first one does work :

http://jsfiddle.net/Dapuc/1/

Comment: With firefox 5.0 it doesn't, it still allows the click through on the inner object

Answer (score 0):

You can add this:

```js
$('#overlayInner').click(function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```